# String Variable not setting initial value

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-entry

```
class Lay():
  def __init__(self):
    root=Tk()
    root.configure(background="black")
    var=StringVar()
    var.set("OVERVIEW")
    Label(root,textvariable=var).grid(row=1,column=1,sticky=W+E+N+S)
    Entry(root, textvariable = var).place(rely=1.0,relx=1.0,x=0,y=0,anchor=SE)
    root.mainloop()
```

Hello, when i run this the initial value of the string variable does not appear, but when i type into the entry box, the text i type appears in the label. I'm not quite sure why this occurs, but i get an empty label to begin with, with the entry box. Thank you for any help.

Comment: I can't reproduce your first issue - the label and entry text is changed on my device. Your second issue is because you're using the same `StringVar`, so updating `var` in the `Entry` updates `var` in your `Label`...

Comment: This is obviously not your complete code - nothing ever calls `Lay()`, so nothing would ever happen.  Something else in your actual code is probably causing the problem - and I suspect it's another call to `Tk()`, which tends to cause problems with Vars (among many other things).  If you want multiple windows, you have to use `Toplevel()` instead for all of them after the first.

Comment: @jasonharper yes the problem was another call to Tk() which I had thought i had delt with, I didn't post the rest of the code because I didn't want to spam code to everyone and tell you to fix it. Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although, I couldn't reproduce the problem, I refactored your code to initialize tkinter widgets through a class(inspired by the snippet in the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.html#a-simple-hello-world-program)) and also increased the window size so that the widgets are clearly viewed. If there is anything else in your code that is calling multiple windows as @jasonharper suggested, you should share that.

```
import tkinter as tk

class Lay(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        super().__init__(master)
        self.master = master        
        self.var=tk.StringVar()
        self.var.set("OVERVIEW")        
        self.Widgets()   


    def Widgets(self):        
        self.displaylbl = tk.Label(self,textvariable=self.var)
        self.displaylbl.grid(row=2,column=1,sticky=tk.W+tk.E+tk.N+tk.S)        
        self.entry = tk.Entry(self, textvariable = self.var)
        self.entry.place(rely=1.0,relx=1.0,x=0,y=0,anchor=tk.SE)


app = Lay()
app.geometry("200x200")
app.mainloop()
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: The problem was as jasonharper suggested. Thank you for refactoring my code also, i did not know you could use a class with tkinter like this. Thank you!